# Sending invoices to members in bulk

Tags: civimail, contributions, invoice

Is there any solution that can bulk email invoices to the members? For example a combination of the two features below:

Email invoice: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/invoicing/

Mass mailings: https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/email/mass-mailings-using-civimail/

Answer (score 3):

I have found the issue. It was a known issue of civicrm v5.25. Here is the details: https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/17164/files

"Invoices - print and email" has been appeared in the dropdown menu after implementing the patch. Thanks everyone for the help

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

- Go to **Contributions menu » Find Contributions** (or use Advanced Search with *Display Results as* set to **Contributions**.
- Search for the invoices you want to send by setting *Contribution Status* to **Pending** and any other criteria you need.
- Select "all X records" or manually select the invoices you want to send from the result.
- From the *Actions* menu, select **Invoices - print or email**.

See attached screenshot.
[image: CiviContribute search actions - "Invoices - print or email"]

Comment: Hi Jon, Thanks for your help. The option "Invoices - print or email" doesn't appear in the list of options on my site. It only has "Receipts - print or email". Does it needs to be enabled somewhere? I'm using CIVICRM 5.24.2. Thanks again Jon

Comment: Hi. Do you have the tax and invoicing already enabled?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that Tax and invoicing have been enabled in the CiviContribute Component Settings.

Thanks Rebecca

Comment: Hi Rebecca, Is "Tax and invoicing" the only component needed to enable "Invoices - print or email"? Thanks @RebeccaTregenna